# How can I test with Internet Explorer while on my Mac?

Tags: windows, virtualization, wine, internet-explorer, microsoft

I work on a Mac, but most of my users are on Windows. What's an easy way to test my websites in IE 7, 8, & 9?  Wine seems kinda buggy and unfriendly.

Comment: Wine _is_ kind of unfriendly, but I have used [PlayOnMac](http://www.playonmac.com/en/) before which greatly improves the user experience. It has a GUI installer for Internet Explorer and might be worth a try before setting up a VM.

Comment: Microsoft now has free Mac virtual machines just for this purpose. https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools

Comment: New tool released by Microsoft -> https://remote.modern.ie/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## A new, better answer.

First I used virtual box.
Then I used browserstack

Now I use parallels

Around for a few years but lately made robust and even friendlier.

It's even easier than the others, setup is easier, saving state is easier, keyboard-mouse integration is better.
Generally its better.

Only item of note is that it cost about $80

which should be petty change for most developer who are paid that in an hour or two.  Paid software is actually my preference - it gives me some confidence that it will actually be maintained going forward.  Plus I'm a developer... paying a... developer.  Seems like a good thing.

Answer (score 39):

I have the *perfect* solution! In 2013, Microsoft released a free officially-supported solution to help Mac developers test with Internet Explorer versions 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, and 11 on Macs:

1. Go to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/
2. Select your desired testing OS ("Mac")
3. Pick a virtualization platform from among VMWare, Parallels, and VirtualBox. If in doubt, choose VirtualBox (which you can [download from the VirtualBox site](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads))
4. Follow the directions to download VMs for the version of IE + Windows you want

Hope this helps.

Comment: AWESOME!!!! Its a shame we need to do this at all, but this is the BEST solution. Great share. Thanks.

Comment: For sure... as a web dev in 2015 I will actually go the extra mile and say its fking ridiculous we have to run a virtualization tool to run a browser just to test... but hey, once they figure out fusion power in another 5 years maybe we will have a better solution lmfao

Comment: Agreed. I wish we could emulate the browsers, or at least install them side-by-side. Too bad Microsoft has a terrible architecture across the board. On a mac the apps could come bundled with all the libs they need to run. Oh well. And as far as Web Dev 2015... Why are we even supporting IE*? *sob*

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is no longer available.

Comment: Looks like they've changed it up, but it should still work for IE11+"Edge Legacy" at least, though this is a far cry from the old separate IE7/IE8/IE9 VMs that I wish I had kept copies of. Here's the new description:  `Test IE11 and Microsoft Edge Legacy using free Windows 10 virtual machines you download and manage locally`

Answer (score 11):

1. Download and Install the free [Oracle Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) Virtual Machine software
2. Utilize the scripts noted in the OS X Daily article [Internet Explorer for Mac the Easy Way: Run IE 7, IE8, & IE9 Free in a Virtual Machine](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/04/internet-explorer-for-mac-ie7-ie8-ie-9-free/) to download, convert and install Microsoft's free IE Testing VMs to be used on VirtualBox.

> We’re going to walk you through how to install Internet Explorer 7, 8, or 9 in a virtual machine running Windows, directly in Mac OS X – for free. This is achieved by using the freely available VirtualBox software from Oracle, and combining that with **free Internet Explorer testing virtual machines from Microsoft**

Here is the scripts presented in the [Article](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/04/internet-explorer-for-mac-ie7-ie8-ie-9-free/):

> ...
>
> **Install ALL versions of Internet Explorer: IE7, IE 8, and IE 9**

```
curl -s https://raw.github.com/xdissent/ievms/master/ievms.sh | bash
```

> **Install Internet Explorer 7 Only**

```
curl -s https://raw.github.com/xdissent/ievms/master/ievms.sh | IEVMS_VERSIONS="7" bash
```

> ...

Comment: These instructions are potentially outdated. Microsoft now distributes Windows + IE 6-11 VMs for web developers in a variety of formats at http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools

Comment: Anirvan, I tried that link and it all seems to be about subscription services (after free trial). Also many of the links don't go anywhere/  Not a solution I can recommend in the current form.

Comment: go to that link, and click "Download a Virtual Machine" (instead of the Browserstack link). I have step by step instructions at http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/103564/1777

Answer (score 4):

The age old question for web designers…

VirtualBox is awesome, but a pain to have multiple versions of Windows taking up space on your hard drive. Another option is using VirtualBox and only installing and running an app like [ietester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) which is only available for Windows but allows you to render multiple versions of IE in one window.

Finally, my personal option of choice is a website called [browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/), You have to pay for it but it's really cheap and well worth it if this is how you make your living. I also own a Windows laptop just for doing thse kind of tests but more often than not use browserstack instead.

Comment: Ah, I remember the days of space being an issue in these decisions.  Nowadays my 500GB drive seems to help quite a lot.

Comment: I wish space wasn't an issue, all of my machines are 500gb plus and by the time I have my apps loaded (adobe master suite, autocad and ableton live+native instruments are the real space hogs here) my hard drive is feeling pretty stuffed already! let alone giving up the hundred odd gig of space it takes to run 5 different versions of windows.

Comment: Yeah, but all I am looking to use is browsers.  I certainly would not want to use Adobe image manipulation tools through an emulator given the drag-drop and other interactivity issues there would be.

Comment: http://crossbrowsertesting.com is also a useful and inexpensive site. It will also allow you local machine access in case you're need to do redirects to a local reverse proxy when you're testing.

Answer (score 3):

Virtualization is definitely the way to go. There's VirtualBox as mentioned above, which is a free open source project. There are also two commercial offerings, [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) and [VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/). Both of those have free trials so you can evaluate what might work best.

If you're wondering why to pay when VirtualBox is free, Parallels and Fusion are both commercially developed and **supported** software. If you run into problems, you can get help, rather than spend time searching for answers yourself. Additionally, VirtualBox is cross-platform, so it has fewer Mac niceties, and it's more of a DIY product - no quick setup or anything.

But you can make the call for yourself. TidBITS has a [fairly recent article](http://tidbits.com/article/12498) comparing Parallels and Fusion, with a good section on VirtualBox as well, and Ars Technica has a pretty comprehensive comparison of the latest versions of Parallels and Fusion.

Hope that's useful for you!

Answer (score 3):

http://www.spoon.net is fantastic tool and the reason I prefer it is it installs *just* the browsers, and side-by-side with your other programs in task bar. It works like a charm, however it is commercial, $12 a month, $60 per year. They plan to publish the app. on Mac soon.

IETester is OK for some basic testing, but it doesn’t handle scripts correctly and therefore is not a 100% reliable testing solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I would add to this as I just found a great new free tool to view IE on a mac. Download "[Sauce](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sauce/id564308477?mt=12)" from the mac app store. I have been using Virtualbox the last two years and this is much easier to install, doesn't have huge VM files, and the interface is much smoother. Sauce also has the ability to preview in IE 10 (which is complete crap). There is also another cloud based app called [browser stack](http://www.browserstack.com/). Tried the free version and the interface is nice but it does cost some $$.

Comment: Note this does not appear to be available in the UK

Answer (score 2):

In addition to virtualization there's Codeweaver's CrossOver

http://www.codeweavers.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to post a comment on @Anirvan's answer which helped me greatly. I'd just like to add that Rey Bango's blog which advocates for security reasons to set Windows Update to automatic causes a problem since IE gets auto-updated as well! MS has created separate auto-blockers for IE 9 through 11. I downloaded all the auto-blocker scripts and created a wrapper to call them on [Dropbox](https://db.tt/OBy4qmzX). Extract the contents of the zip file and run IE9-11_blocker.cmd to block IE 9 through 11.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not as professional as the other answers, but if one just wants to see how IE is rendering the site, the following options are free and work without any heavy installation:

- Google Chrome Extension **IE Tab** (Windows only)
- Google Chrome Extension **IE-On-Chrome**
- https://netrenderer.com/
- http://browsershots.org/

Note that none of them work locally (i.e localhost or 127.0.0.1).

Similar questions were asked in SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426498/online-internet-explorer-simulators) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844682/is-there-a-ie-tester-for-mac)), but they are pretty old and the topics are closed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Safari and navigate to **Safari > Preferences** from the menu bar.
2. Click on the **Advanced** tab.
3. Check the **"Show Develop menu in menu bar"** setting, then close the Preferences window.
4. The **Develop** **menu** should now show in your menu bar.
5. Go to **Develop > User Agent**.
6. Here, you have to option to choose different browser options like ***Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer 7, 8, 9, 10*** and ***11***. You can also choose ***Firefox*** and ***Chrome*** as the **User Agent**.

*Source*: [How to view websites on your Mac that require Internet Explorer (or a PC)](https://www.imore.com/how-view-websites-your-mac-require-internet-explorer-or-pc)

Comment: This is more of a way to access some picky websites that require IE, but no substitute for testing a page with _actual Internet Explorer_, which the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through [these ways to test IE on Mac machine](https://dzone.com/articles/7-ways-you-can-test-your-website-on-internet-explo)

Also, you can use online platforms like LambdaTest, Sauce Labs or Browserstack to access Internet Explorer using Mac machine.

Some software from the above link:

- [Remote IE](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417?mt=12)
- [Cross browser testing tool](https://www.lambdatest.com/)
- [Oracle VM Virtual Box](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html)

Comment: could you list some of the softwares from the link in case the link breaks? Use [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/367140/edit) feature.

Comment: How does installing RDP (your first link) help to test with IE, isn't there a Windows machine required somewhere?

Comment: @nohillside Apple provides Microsoft Remote app. With the Microsoft Remote Desktop app, you can connect to a remote PC and your work resources from almost anywhere.
https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417?mt=12